# Was für eine Entsprechung hat "pharma salt" im Deutschen?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, technical-terminology

Kontext:

> The NaCl slurry for the pharma salt production is discharged from the Salt Leg SL1 and pumped into the controlled pharma salt production area, where it is dewatered by the Centrifuge CE2 and finally dried by the live steam driven Dryer DR2.

Bei Google finde ich "Pharmasalz" und "pharmazeutisches Salz".

Comment: Du hast deine Frage im letzten Satz selbst beantwortet.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast nur weil Anna diese zwei Begriffe _via_ Google findet, heißt das nicht, das beide richtig sind oder gleich häufig verwendet werden. Von daher finde ich die Frage durchaus berechtigt.

Comment: Du hast Recht, danke.

Answer (score 1):

Your search results are correct. The direct equivalent to "pharma salt" is

> Pharmasalz

"Pharmazeutisches Salz" would correspond to "pharmaceutical salt".